# Golang looks for packages in GOROOT instead of GOPATH

Tags: go

I'm trying to run a simple Go program, with the following setup:

```
// main.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "db"
    "webapp"
)

func main() {
    database := db.New()
    webapp.StartServer(&database, &notifierClient)
}
```

I get the following import errors:

```sh
main.go:8:2: package db is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\db)
main.go:9:2: package webapp is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\webapp)
```

The folder structure I have is:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Golang\src\MyProject\source
    main.go
    go.mod
    go.sum
    db/     several .go files
    webapp/ several .go files
```

I've run `go mod init` and my `GOPATH` is set to `C:\Users\User\Documents\Golang\` but it keeps searching for local import modules in `GOROOT`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I would recommend using go mod. `go mod init somegit.com/someuser/somemodule` and then `go mod tidy`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add your module name e.g. `myapp` before the import path:

```
import (
    "myapp/db"
    "myapp/webapp"
)
```

---

[Code organization](https://go.dev/doc/code#Organization):

> An import path is a string used to import a package. A package's import path is its module path joined with its subdirectory within the module. For example, the module github.com/google/go-cmp contains a package in the directory cmp/. That package's import path is github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp. Packages in the standard library do not have a module path prefix.

---

[New module changes in Go 1.16](https://go.dev/blog/go116-module-changes):

Modules on by default
The go command now builds packages in module-aware mode by default, even when no go.mod is present. This is a big step toward using modules in all projects.

It’s still possible to build packages in GOPATH mode by setting the GO111MODULE environment variable to off. You can also set GO111MODULE to auto to enable module-aware mode only when a go.mod file is present in the current directory or any parent directory. This was previously the default. Note that you can set GO111MODULE and other variables permanently with go env -w:

go env -w GO111MODULE=auto
We plan to drop support for GOPATH mode in Go 1.17. In other words, Go 1.17 will ignore GO111MODULE. If you have projects that do not build in module-aware mode, now is the time to migrate. If there is a problem preventing you from migrating, please consider filing an issue or an experience report.

---

For the sake of clarity - My test structure is:

```
 go version
go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64
```

[image]

Just a working example (`main.go` file):

```
package main

import (
    "myapp/db"
    "myapp/webapp"
)

func main() {
    database := db.New()
    webapp.StartServer(&database, &notifierClient)
}

var notifierClient = "Test"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Debug Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you! this worked. I also had to turn the modules on an off so it started looking in GOPATH: go env -w GO111MODULE=on and then =off again

Comment: You're welcome, My env is: `GO111MODULE=""` and you do not need to work inside $GOPTH